# How to most effectively get the first preceding/subsequent entry outside a given time interval?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

We have a SQL Server DB that contains a large table (>100M rows) with archive values, basically in the form of `[Id], [StationId], [DatapointId], [Timestamp], [Value]`. As the stations do not get polled, there aren't any regular intervals at which a station sends a datapoint, so the timestamps are set to arbitrary times.

For our web visualization, I need to extract entries from this table for a pannable chart that I'm building with D3.js. I need to query by `StationId`, `DatapointId`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`. This is simple and works as expected, but for the line chart that it feeds, I do need additional data, namely the first value *before* the chosen time interval, and (if there is one) the first value *after* the interval. This is neccessary to draw the line from the left resp. right boundary of the chart to the first/last value within the interval (otherwise the data within the chart would look somewhat "isolated" because the line stops before the charts boundaries, like there's no data before or after the values in the chosen interval).

At the moment I need to run 3 queries: one to get the data within the interval, one to retrieve the first matching row *before* `StartDate`, and anotherone to get the first matching row after `EndDate`.

It works, and after creating a covering index the speed is ok, but I think there might be a way to reduce the number of roundtrips to the DB. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, could you add the query you tried,your sql server version, and if possible the table definition + sample data?

Comment: Do you notice any performance issues as a result of the three trips to the database? Unless it's causing an issue, your existing solution might be good enough. There are always windowing functions you can use (SQL Server 2012+) if you really want to reduce the number of trips, but basically you need to decide if it's worth the effort.

Comment: Please edit the question andd the query you use. It's not clear if you query for a single StationID, for a single (StationID, DatapointID) combination or for all stations in a specific time range.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did not show my queries because I did not want to bias your answers, they are very basic *select/select top where* thingies anyway. I need to query for a single StationId and a single DatapointId at a time.

Comment: @RandolphWest: The performance is ok, but the chance of reducing the execution time by 2/3 is very tempting. Thanks for mentioning windowing functions, I'll have a look at that!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you query for all data (from all stations) in a specific time range.

You can probably write this with window functions (and it might be more efficient) but here is one method, with `OUTER APPLY`.

(The `ds` subquery is only used to get a list of distinct `StationID`. It should be replaced with the `Stations` table you likely have):

```
SELECT
    ds.[StationID],                   -- station
    st.ExtendedStartDate,             -- extended start and
    en.ExtendedEndDate                -- and end dates

    tt.[Timestamp],                   -- timestamps and data
    tt.[DatapointId],
    tt.[Value]
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT [StationID]
      FROM ArchiveTable
    ) AS ds
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) s.[Timestamp] AS ExtendedStartDate
      FROM ArchiveTable AS s
      WHERE s.[StationId] = ds.[StationId]
        AND s.[Timestamp] < @StartDate
      ORDER BY s.[Timestamp] DESC
    ) AS st
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) e.[Timestamp] AS ExtendedEndDate
      FROM ArchiveTable AS e
      WHERE e.[StationId] = ds.[StationId]
        AND e.[Timestamp] > @EndDate
      ORDER BY e.[Timestamp] ASC
    ) AS en
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT t.*
      FROM ArchiveTable AS t
      WHERE t.[StationId] = ds.[StationId]
        AND t.[Timestamp] >= COALESCE(st.ExtendedStartDate, @StartDate)
        AND t.[Timestamp] <= COALESCE(en.ExtendedEndDate, @EndDate)  
    ) AS tt ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking roundtrips to the database should not be an issue, if you want to send them to the db as one query, you could do that by using `CTE`'s and `UNION ALL` operators.

> I need to query for a single StationId and a single DatapointId at a
>   time

The query below filters on `StationId`, `DatapointID` and the `StartDate` and `EndDate` using the `timestamp` column.

```
--Filter params

DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2019-02-20 8:48:08.633'
DECLARE @EndDate datetime2 = '2019-02-20 10:48:08.633'
DECLARE @stationid int = 1
DECLARE @DatapointId int = 1

--Query

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TOP(1) [StationId],[DatapointId],[TimeStamp] 
FROM PollingTable 
WHERE [TimeStamp] < @startdate
      AND StationId =  @stationId 
      AND [DatapointId] = @Datapointid
ORDER BY [TimeStamp] desc
)
,CTE2 AS
(
SELECT TOP(1) [StationId],[DatapointId],[TimeStamp] 
FROM PollingTable 
WHERE [TimeStamp] > @EndDate
      AND StationId =  @stationId 
      AND [DatapointId] = @Datapointid
ORDER BY [TimeStamp] asc
)
SELECT [StationId],[DatapointId],[TimeStamp]
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT [StationId],[DatapointId],[TimeStamp] 
FROM PollingTable 
WHERE [TimeStamp] >= @startdate 
      AND [TimeStamp] <= @EndDate
      AND StationId =  @stationId 
      AND [DatapointId] = @Datapointid
UNION ALL
SELECT [StationId],[DatapointId],[TimeStamp] 
FROM CTE2;
```

**Afterwards, this index was added**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_StationId_DatapointId_TimeStamp on PollingTable(StationId,DatapointId,TimeStamp)
```

Resulting in seeks on my end, but you might have to swap columns around depending on how your dataset is distributed. My dataset is nowhere near yours.

[image]